# remove portion of string that is found in a list

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to find an elegant way to remove data that is contained in a list from a single string. A simple complete example is shown below that does *not* work:

```
private string removeWebSuffixes()
{ 
    string siteName="someSite.com";

    List<string> siteNames=new List<string>{siteName};
    List<string> domainSuffixes=new List<string>{".net",".com",".gov"};

    domainSuffixes.ForEach(x=>siteName.Replace(x,""));

    return siteName;//actually, should return result of siteName.replace statement
}
```

I think this example cannot work because the replace statement is not returning the value to anything, but i have included it because i think it clearly conveys what I am trying to accomplish.

I bet there is an easy to do this (and i don't mean a foreach loop), but I'm not seeing it. Yet.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace()` doesn't actually change the string. You need to write the return value back to the original string if you want to keep the change:

```
domainSuffixes.ForEach(x => siteName = siteName.Replace(x, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with before seeing Justin's response:

```
private string removeDomainSuffix(string siteName)
{ 
    List<string> siteNames=new List<string>(){siteName};
    List<string> domainNames=General.GetWebDomains();

    var truncated= 
    (
      from sites in siteNames
      from suffixes in domainNames
      select new { results=(sites.Replace(suffixes,"")) }
      ).OrderBy(x=>x.results.Length).Take(1); 

    foreach(var v in truncated)
      return (string.Format("{0}",v.results));

    return siteName;
}
```

It works, but it is not as good as his, and i couldn't figure out how to get the single string out of the var without resorting to the loop.

Hope I don't get in trouble for posting this solution here as well. I will mark Justin's as the answer.